# http get url modification in angular 1.6

Tags: http, url, https, url-rewriting, angular1.6

I have an angular 1.6 project. My application base url is https://localhost/abc/#/

I want to write a http service call to get client details : https://localhost/api/ccc/v1/client

But when i'm passing the url to http.get() it is hitting https://localhost/abc/api/ccc/v1/client

```
function getClient() {
    var url = "api/ccc/v1/client";
    return $http.get(url).then((response) => {
      return response;
    });
}
```

How can i remove "abc" from my url to hit this (https://localhost/api/ccc/v1/client) exact api ?
can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue by adding **( / )** to url.

"var url = "/api/ccc/v1/client";"

Now, I'm able to hit this (https://localhost/api/ccc/v1/client) exact api to get  client details.

Updated code

```
function getClient() {
    var url = "/api/ccc/v1/client";
    return $http.get(url).then((response) => {
      return response;
    });
}
```